# How to add a scrollbar to a tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I don't know how to add a scrollbar to this window. Here's the code:

```
def winHelp():
    winHelp = tk.Tk()
    winHelp.geometry("700x700")
    winHelp.title("Help")

    line1label = tk.Label(winHelp, text="Radioactive Decay Calculator: \n")
```

There will be some text here that will fill up the window:

```
line1label.grid(row=0)
line1label.config(justify=LEFT)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking a Tkinter scrollbar, you should tag Tkinter also. For applying Tkinter scrollbar you should use below code.`scroll_bar = Scrollbar(master, option,..)`
where master is a parent window.

Comment: This answer is very misleading. It implies that all you need to do is all a scrollbar widget to be able to scroll everything in a window, and that's not true.